# Reading an Xml file and making a word bold in a flowdocument

Tags: vb.net

Placing the following text in inlines of a paragraph of a flowdocument in XAML, makes the word "charge" bold. But reading the same text from an xml file with xmlreader.ReadInnerXml does nothing.

The resistance of the ions and electrons to this flow of charge  causes ohmic heating of the plasma.

How can I make the word bold?

```
'Part of the code reading the xml file and displaying the content in a flowdocument
    x.ReadToFollowing("Paragraph")
     Dim b As String = x.ReadInnerXml
     paragraph.Inlines.Add(b)
     flowdocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph)
     flowdocumentscrollviewer.Document=flowdocument
```

Part of the xml file:

```
<HelpDocuments>
  <ICPCanvas1Help Num="1">
     <Paragraph Color="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Alignment="0" FontSize="14">
 This interaction causes the ions and electrons
within the coil to flow in the closed annular paths
shown in the window. The resistance of the ions and
electrons to this flow of<Run FontWeight="Bold"> charge </Run> causes ohmic heating of
the plasma.      
    </Paragraph>
  </ICPCanvas1Help>
</HelpDocuments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following tags around the word you want to bold.

`<Run FontWeight="bold">charge</Run>`

Comment: This tag was actually there, but the word processor omitted it. This will not solve my problem, when reading from an Xml File to a flowdocument.

Comment: What is it not rendering in? What processor?

Comment: I mean stackoverflow omitted the tag from my text. The code above works when it is in Xaml, but does not work when read from an Xml file. In my xml file the above code is present, but it does not make any thing bold. In the flowDocument that I import the xml file contents, the above code is present like other texts and does not make anything bold.

Comment: how are you displaying the contents? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Part of my xml file is as follows: